# how to Generate Dynamic Controll in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, controls

I want to **generate Control dynamically by user specific value.**
Like i have EditText for ControlId, Control Width, Control Height etc.
based on that value i want to generate control

```
LinearLayout L1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    L1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams L1paeam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    L1.setLayoutParams(L1paeam);

    TextView T1 = new TextView(this);
    T1.setText(R.string.Dynamic_text);
    L1.addView(T1);

    Button B1=new Button(this);
    B1.setText("Dynamic Button");
    L1.addView(B1);

    setContentView(L1);
```

In this code the control-id Layout_height and Layout_width are specified but i want them as user specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution i found.

```
public void generateButton(String Id,int Width,int Height,String text){
    @IdRes
            int id = Integer.parseInt(Id);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams L1param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Width, Height);
    final Button B1=new Button(this);
    B1.setId(id);
    B1.setText(text);
    B1.setLayoutParams(L1param);
    B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Button click operation goes here
        }
    });
    layout_main.addView(B1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any View in view container (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) and remove those views in runtime. Create view and specify layout params for that view.